# jQgrid search returns all records where clause doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, search, jqgrid

I have a simple jQgrid with the toolbar(navGrid) for add, edit, delete and search. The problem is that search doesn't work. It seems to always return all of the records from the table instead of one, meaning there is something wrong with the where clause, that I'm trying to generate depending on what is given in the search modal window. Or it might be that the search case isn't activated at all..

here is the grid code:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "server.php",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        colNames: ["Driver ID", "Name", "Country", "Victories", "Poles",     
"Titles", "Fastest laps"], //"Team name"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "driverid", index:"driverid", width: 55, search:true,             stype:'text', editable:false},
        { name: "name", index:"name", width: 90, search:true, stype:'text', editable:true },
        { name: "country", index:"country", width: 90, search:true, stype:'text', editable:true },
        { name: "victories", index:"victories", width: 80, search:true, align: "right", editable:true },
        { name: "poles", index:"poles", width: 80, search:true, align: "right", editable:true },
        { name: "titles", index:"titles", width: 80, search:true, align: "right", editable:true },
        { name: "flaps", index:"flaps", width: 80, search:true,  align: "right", editable:true}
        //{ name: "teamName", width: 80, align: "right", editable:true}
        ],
        autowidth: true,
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: "driverid",
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        caption: "F1 statistics grid",
        editurl: "dbedit.php"
    }); 
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:true,del:true,edit:true,search:true});
});
```

Here is the part from dbedit.php:

```
include("connection.php"); //

$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error()); 

// select the database 
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error connecting to db."); 


$action="";
if (isset($_POST['oper']))
{
$action=$_POST['oper'];

}
else
{
echo "Definisi akciju";
exit();
}

switch ($action)
{

case "add":
{

    $driverid  =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['driverid']); 
    $name  =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
    $country =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']); 
    $victories    =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['victories']);
    $poles   =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['poles']);      
    $titles  =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titles']); 
    $flaps   =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['flaps']);
    //$teamName   =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['teamName']);  
    //$insert = 'INSERT INTO '.'drivers';  
    //$insert .= ' VALUES (NULL,';
        //$insert .="'".$name."','".$country."', '".$victories."','".$poles."', '".$titles."', '".$flaps."')";

    $insert = "INSERT INTO drivers (driverid, name, country, victories, poles, titles, flaps) VALUES (Null,'".$name."','".$country."','".$victories."','".$poles."','".$titles."','".$flaps."')";



    $result = mysql_query( $insert ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 
    //$_SESSION['nesto'] = $result;
}
break;

case "edit":
{
    $driverid  =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $name  =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
    $country =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']); 
    $victories    =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['victories']);
    $poles   =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['poles']);      
    $titles  =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titles']); 
    $flaps   =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['flaps']);  
    $update = 'UPDATE drivers'." SET name='". $name ."', country='" . $country ."', victories='" . $victories ."', poles='" . $poles ."', titles='" . $titles ."', flaps='" . $flaps. "' WHERE driverid=". $driverid ;
//echo $update;
    $result = mysql_query( $update ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 
}


break;
case "del":
{

$driverid  =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']); //id reda iz grida
$delete = 'DELETE FROM drivers WHERE driverid='.$driverid;
$result = mysql_query( $delete ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 

}
break;

case "search":
{
$page = $_POST['page']; 

// get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum parameter in the grid 
 $limit = $_POST['rows']; 
 //echo $limit;
// get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
// after that the index from colModel 
$sidx = $_POST['sidx']; 

// sorting order - at first time sortorder 
$sord = $_POST['sord']; 

// if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; 





$ops = array(
'eq'=>'=', //equal
'ne'=>'<>',//not equal
'lt'=>'<', //less than
'le'=>'<=',//less than or equal
'gt'=>'>', //greater than
'ge'=>'>=',//greater than or equal
'bw'=>'LIKE', //begins with
'bn'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't begin with
'in'=>'LIKE', //is in
'ni'=>'NOT LIKE', //is not in
'ew'=>'LIKE', //ends with
'en'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't end with
'cn'=>'LIKE', // contains
'nc'=>'NOT LIKE'  //doesn't contain
);

function getWhereClause($col, $oper, $val){
global $ops;
//if($oper == 'eq' || $oper == 'ne') $val .= "";
if($oper == 'bw' || $oper == 'bn') $val .= '%';
if($oper == 'ew' || $oper == 'en' ) $val = '%'.$val;
if($oper == 'cn' || $oper == 'nc' || $oper == 'in' || $oper == 'ni') $val = '%'.$val.'%';
return " WHERE $col {$ops[$oper]} '$val' ";
}

$where = ""; //if there is no search request sent by jqgrid, $where should be empty
$searchField = isset($_POST['searchField']) ? $_POST['searchField'] : false;
$searchOper = isset($_POST['searchOper']) ? $_POST['searchOper']: false;
$searchString = isset($_POST['searchString']) ? $_POST['searchString'] : false;

if ($_POST['_search'] == 'true') {
$where = getWhereClause($searchField,$searchOper,$searchString);
}

// connect to the MySQL database server 
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Connection Error: " .     mysql_error()); 

// select the database 
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error connecting to db."); 

// calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM drivers ".$where.")";
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM drivers a, teams b WHERE     "."a.driverid=b.driver1id".""); 
//echo $result1;
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);  
$count = $row['count']; 
//$_SESSION['nesto'] = $count;
// calculate the total pages for the query 
if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
$total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
$total_pages = 0; 
} 

// if for some reasons the requested page is greater than the total 
// set the requested page to total page 
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

// calculate the starting position of the rows 
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;

// if for some reasons start position is negative set it to 0 
// typical case is that the user type 0 for the requested page 
if($start <0) $start = 0; 

// the actual query for the grid data 

 $SQL = "SELECT driverid, name, country, victories, poles, titles, flaps FROM drivers ".$where;
 //$SQL = "SELECT "."a.driverid, a.name, a.country, a.victories, a.poles, a.titles,  a.flaps, b.teamName"." FROM drivers a, teams b WHERE a.driverid=b.driver1id OR  a.driverid=b.driver2id ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";


//echo $SQL;
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 
//$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error());


$response=null;
$response->page = $page;
$response->total = $total_pages;
$response->records = $count;
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$response->rows[$i]['id']=$row['driverid'];
$response->rows[$i] ['cell']=array($row['driverid'],$row['name'],$row['country'],$row['victories'],$row['poles'],$row['titles'],$row['flaps']);//,$row['teamName']);
$i++;
}        
echo json_encode($response);

}
```

I've gone through the code 20 times, to see if I've typed something wrong and I can't see it. Is it something that I missed when I defined the grid, or the colModel?

Answer (score 0):

I've lost many hours trying to figure this out. Finally, I've put loadonce:true in the grid code and it worked. So, try that. Put it anywhere, for example underneath the: viewrecords: true

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tried that, it didn't work because there was a crucial thing I missed, and that was that search is a simple data showing, meaning that all the code for managing search, should be in the url file, in my case it is server.php. Now it works fine.

Comment: Wait, so you leave 'case: "search" {}' empty? And all that code you put in server.php file? If not, can you explain please what do you put in server.php and what in case "search"? I would like to do it that way too, but nothing I try works.